# I am trying to retrieve data from form in a view and all values are null C#

Tags: c#, .net

Here is the code for my controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Save(Customer customer)
    {



        Page.db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT into Customer(Name, Email, PhoneNumber, Address, Quantity) VALUES(@Name, @Email, @PhoneNumber, @Address, @Quantity)",
            new SqlParameter("@Name", customer.Name),
            new SqlParameter("@Email", customer.Email),
            new SqlParameter("@PhoneNumber", customer.PhoneNumber),
            new SqlParameter("@Address", customer.Address),
            new SqlParameter("@Quantity", customer.Quantity)
            );

        Page.db.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
```

Here is the code from my View.

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Events"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal buyer-info">
        <h1>Purchase</h1>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customers.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customers.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customers.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customers.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customers.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customers.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customers.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customers.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customers.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customers.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customers.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customers.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customers.Quantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customers.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { min = 1, max = 5, @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customers.Quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

i dont know what i am doing wrong because i am submitting the data from my view but when i run it in the debugger,

```
public ActionResult Save(Customer customer)
```

the "customer" is returning null values.

My first time doing this so if the mistake is obvious please dont rage.

Comment: What are the resulting HTML form elements being created on the page?  What does the `Customer` class look like?  There may be a disconnect between `Customer` and whatever `model.Customers` is.

Comment: Where customer is returning ? I think you are just passing the customer to the actionMethod and from no where the customer is returning. Have you debugged the code because I see no errors in your code.

Comment: Thanks David and Adeel there was a disconnect between customer ill put an answer up now. Greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so basically my controller inherits off a base controller which has the Object "Page". In this object i have something like this:

```
  public Entities = new Entities();
  public Example1 Example { get; set; }
  public Example2 Example { get; set; }
  public Customer customer {get;set; }
```

So here i have declared all my entities so i can use this to pull the data. 
What i was doing is ADDING THE USING DIRECTIVE "using ProjectName.Model.Customer". HOWEVER in my view i was using @model Page therefore the reason for my code not working.

So this is what i added.

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Save(Page page)
    {

        Page.db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT into Customer(Name, Email, PhoneNumber, Address, Quantity) VALUES(@Name, @Email, @PhoneNumber, @Address, @Quantity)",
            new SqlParameter("@Name",page.customer.Name),
            new SqlParameter("@Email", page.customer.Email),
            new SqlParameter("@PhoneNumber", page.customer.PhoneNumber),
            new SqlParameter("@Address", page.customer.Address),
            new SqlParameter("@Quantity", page.customer.Quantity)
            );

        Page.db.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
```

So, what i did was change Customer customer to Page page and i was not changing the view. DESPITE all this, when i ran it i got a "Object reference not equal to an instance of an object". So i had to add this.

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Save(Page page)
    {
        Page.Customers = page.Customers;

        Page.db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT into Customer(Name, Email, PhoneNumber, Address, Quantity) VALUES(@Name, @Email, @PhoneNumber, @Address, @Quantity)",
            new SqlParameter("@Name",page.customer.Name),
            new SqlParameter("@Email", page.customer.Email),
            new SqlParameter("@PhoneNumber", page.customer.PhoneNumber),
            new SqlParameter("@Address", page.customer.Address),
            new SqlParameter("@Quantity", page.customer.Quantity)
            );

        Page.db.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
```

As you may realize i added 
`Page.Customers = page.Customers;` then when i ran the code it all worked and happy days. Thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 0):

FormMethod.Post u have to add in razor helpe

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Events",FormMethod.Post))
```